# How to use a role in template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

My cloudformation template fails due to this line...

```
IamFleetRole: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/spot.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2Spot'
```

But I am sure this role exist in my account:

```
arn:aws:iam::3308XXXX3566:role/aws-service-role/spot.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2Spot
```

I am not sure why do I get this error...

> SpotFleetRequestConfig.IamFleetRole is invalid.

Comment: Have you created this service role yourself? If so, have you checked that the role has correct trusted entities and permissions as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html?  Specifically: `On the Select type of trusted entity page, choose EC2, EC2 - Spot Instances`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this page:

https://ec2spotworkshops.com/launching_ec2_spot_instances/spot_fleet.html

If you have never launched a Spot Fleet, the AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet won’t exist in your account. To create it run the following command in AWS CloudShell:

```
aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name spotfleet.amazonaws.com
```

After running the command, it worked with this new path in template ...

```
        IamFleetRole: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/spotfleet.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet'
```